# How to skip/remove invalid non-utf8 characters from a xml file

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I'm looking for a method to delete/skip non-utf8 caracters from a xml file.
I'm using simplexml_load_string(), but when the file has non-utf8 character i'm getting error "parser error : CharRef: invalid hexadecimal value", and code it's looking like that:

```
Q7fzÕ6,¯å1òw~Ò`H-7%¨§ÃU³^Ôàƒ³‡Îá_s…“w²žrâºæºçYF#K‰àa¥²o8ÎkìŽ»qíNž‚ËÂUeJvgXêõ»&apos;[Hw®Èl[-&#xAEPs§æŠ§£gáRÓ„Å2Ì$ŽŽŠŽÆÁœ˜.E~Ñ°@=
```

and i can't save information from that xml, i was trying many solutin from web/stackoverflow no one was helping me. 
I was trying with preg_replace, etc. 
Thanks !

Comment: The problem is not with weirdly-looking characters (which are valid per se), but rather with broken entities like `&#xAEP`. Try removing/escaping ampersands in this text or wrap it in a `CDATA` block.

Comment: @georg Yep, you have right, $string = str_replace('&', ' ', $string); and my code is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from comment:

> Try removing/escaping ampersands in this text or wrap it in a CDATA
>   block

So i put before call function
`simplexml_load_string($string)`

 this

 `$string = str_replace('&', ' ', $string);`.

 and now it's work, no & in string so simplexml_load_string() can parse without errors.